# Сделать первые 3 буквы другим цветом

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Есть слово, возможно ли сделать первые 3 буквы другим цветом, не прибегая к html и js

Comment: css элемент:first-letter { ... }

Comment: @Виктор первые три, не просто первая :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 ну я направление дал:)

Comment: @Дмитрий, такое невозможно, начнём с того что если вы собираетесь делать это в HTML, то без HTML такое сделать в принципе нельзя. А средства CSS не позволяют выбирать первые три буквы, так что, тут либо нужно вручную сделать разделение в HTML дав класс элементу и менять цвет в стилях, либо провернуть такое через JavaScript.

Comment: @Виктор, Направление на "три весёлых" буквы?.)

Comment: Зачем вы отметили вопрос метками HTML и JavaScript если вы их не собираетесь использовать?

Comment: бред но можно: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNyRrew

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, нельзя. В зависимости от ширины букв будет меняться закрашиваемая часть. Замени у себя слово с `heading` на `hmmading`. Сработает только для моноширинных шрифтов.

Comment: @Grundy согласен, я проверил: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNyRrew и получается через Жо...

Answer (score 0):

В `css` отсутствует псевдоэлемент типа `:nth-letter`

Но как вариант, можно сделать так

```css
p {
  position: relative;
}

p::before {
  content: "Wow";
  color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Wow text text</p>
```

Comment: `не прибегая к html`

Comment: @ΝNL993 обновил

Comment: Не работает с `\nWow` (Я поменял и в тексте и в CSS)

Comment: @ΝNL993 - это решение не решает всех задач,  поэтому без js здесь не обойтись или менять html

Comment: @ΝNL993 - вполне возможно, данное решение подойдет автору вопроса

Comment: Возможно, но он вообще не реагировал на *любые* сообщения с того момента как задал вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Придётся вручную обернуть первые три буквы в тег `<span>`.

```css
.initial {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="initial">Lor</span>em ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
```

Comment: Вы использовали HTML, по условиям задачи вы уже сделали неправильно

Comment: ΝNL993, был невнимателен, показалось, что в условии — "без JS ". Но это же дикость, а не вопрос. Он бы ещё написал, чтобы и без стилей, и был бы фулл-хаОс и взрыв мозга.)

Comment: Я знаю :). Советую вам поставить голос "против" чтобы "Дух сообщества" удалил вопрос, т.к. в этом вопросе нет никакого смысла, первое, потому что правильного ответа на него не может существовать, второе сами условия в вопросе невозможные.

Comment: @ΝNL993, формально, правильным ответом как раз и будет: для предложенных ограничений решить задачу невозможно.

Answer (score -2):

```css
#x:before{content: 'foo bar';
background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 1.4em, black 1.5em);
color: transparent;
background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h2 id='x'></h2>
```

Comment: +. И как мне самому в голову не пришло? background-clip: text; — лишний.

Comment: Можно вместо `#x` написать `body`, тогда от HTML можно будет вовсе избавиться ;)

Comment: Попробуйте в начале текста добавить `* `, или `\x `. Тогда неправильно цвет лезет.

Comment: Плохой вариант, для каждых новых трех букв надо будет пересчитывать конфигурацию для градиента. Например, замени в своем примере `foo` на `mmm` - и увидишь, что красный цвет только полторы буквы покрывает

Comment: @stylok не понимаю вашего негодования, если на ваших ответах минусы ставил один пользователь, то его минусы откатятся, если их (минусов) будет много. А [оскорбления в StackOverflow запрещены в принципе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks).

Comment: @stylok 1. из текста: `В том числе, но не ограничиваясь: травля, шантаж, **нецензурная лексика**, бла бла...`. Оскорбления не в адрес кого-то, а просто существуют :). 2. Мне лично всё равно, имеет ответ брань или нет (главное чтобы он помогал участникам), но по правил я должен пожаловаться на него. Также я не считаю что ответу ставили минусы из-за мата, думаю дело в том сам ответ (решение задачи) плохой и поэтому появились минусы. А откуда у вас безделье не понимаю :), вроде бы по программированию кучу материала есть который можно и нужно учить.

Comment: Странно. я пытался удалить и переопубликовать свой коммент с запоздавшей правкой, но... спасибо, что продолжили тему и без оного. Там ремаркой был другой контекст, как и в "проёЖенной" мессаге. Суть? — комментарий под которым мы бубним и правда хорош и оригинален. А весь этот свистопердёжь о нецензурщине даже рядом не стоял на фоне неожиданного решения. Я, если помните, правильно переозвучил свой посыл? То, что приводил в пример себя? Скорее частность и эпизодические наблюдения над русскоязычной частью ресурса. Минусы за правильные ответы на некорректные вопросы? Это какой-то звиздец.

Comment: Что касаемо "свободного времени"... так уж получилось, что в кои-то века, закопавшись в расширения для браузеров (не первый раз, но с первого манифеста), а сейчас, когда пытаюсь освоить грядущее — 
 третий... гулежом попадаю либо в убогие и лаконичные описания оффдоков, либо в "stack", чаще приходится методом научного тыка, вот и подумалось, что не потратить ли свою болталогию с пользой для окружающих. Коль уж я разбираюсь в большинстве вопросов куда "лучше, чем... армянин"  ))

Comment: [Полагаю что нам стоит продолжить обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141273/3---), не стоит слишком загружать комментарии.