# CSS Возможно ли заменить стили части фразы без дополнительных тегов?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть довольно частая задача от дизайнеров, по разукрашиванию конкретных частей фразы заголовков в отдельные цвета. Пример.

[image: Test image]

Большенство версий в верстке сводиться к добавлению сторонних тегов в фразу, по типу.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #110929;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  ;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 250px;
}

h1 b {
  color: #1C51FE;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<h1>Create Your Own <b>NFT Dream</b> Gallery</h1>
```

Вопрос - Есть ли решения, при которых в тег заголовка `<h1>` не надо вставлять дополнительных тегов, для стилизации ? (По типу `<b>` и аналогов)
*Думал про `data` атрибуты, абсолютное позиционирование и `:before` с контентом, но если текст должен быть адаптивным, нормальной реализации не получилось. Возможно кто-то знает эффективное решение ?

Comment: Нет. Да и не нужно. Это же *выделение*, так что какой-то выделяющий тег тут не помешает.

Comment: Нет, мне кажется лучше всего использовать простой `span`.

Comment: [кривой, не эффективный, но дополнительных тегов не требует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476388/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-3-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc/1476414#1476414) p.s. `font-family: monospace` для более точного попадания в нужные позиции не помешает(хотя дизайн вероятнее всего испортит). и да, оно только цвет менять позволяет. еще можно с `::first-line, ::firts-letter` поиграться

Comment: @puffleeck Спасибо, я пробовал что-то похожее, но вот на текущем примере, когда это не первое и не последнее слово у меня не получаеться сменить стиль.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 самому элементу с текстом задаете что то подобное: `background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 10%, red 5em, transparent 10%)` транспарент - типа прозрачный. можно еще опять же докинуть `::first-line` или наоборот `not(::first-line)` чтоб лишние строки не цеплял. еще овальный градиент можно попробовать, или коник градиент. borderы еще...